# Recursively update every element of multidimensional array

Tags: php, recursion, multidimensional-array

I have a large multidimensional array like this:

```
$array = [
    'a' => 1,
    'b' => 5,
    'c' => [
        'c1' => 12,
        'c2' => [
            'd1' = 4,
            'd2' => 25
        ],
        'c3' => [/*...*/]
    ]
];
```

The array is of unknown size and dimension and I am trying to modify each element, for example to add 1 to every elements value.

I've been googling around and found some recursive functions that visit each element and print its contents out, but nothing about modifying each element as you go.

The following code (that I found online)

```
function x($a) {
    if (!is_array($a)) {
        echo ($a+1);
        return;
    }

    foreach($a as $v) {
        x($v);
    }
}
```

allows me to print out the contents of the array, but how do you modify this to actually update the array elements with the calculation instead of echoing it out?

Answer (score 2):

```
array_walk_recursive ($array, function (&$val) {  $val += 1; });
print_r($array);
```